# How can i do a console like CatLog uses?

Tags: android, console

I need to do a console to display a information about sincronization process.

I think i can use a EditText but it does not look like a CatLog's console.

I appreciate any idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be Custom Listview with TextViews (or) Table view inside activity?

Comment: Thanks. I gonna try using that.